# Jupyter: "notebook" is not a jupyter command

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I want to have jupyter notebook installed. But on my MacBook Pro (OS X El Capitan) and my web server (Debian 7), I get the same error: jupyter notebook is not a jupyter command.

I just follow the official installation instruction. And no error occurs during installation.

I searched for solutions but none of them works. What should I do now?

Comment: You may need to install the jupyter-notebook package separately. I needed to do this on Arch Linux, not sure how it is on OS X or Debian.

Comment: `pip install notebook`

Comment: @crunch it doesn't work.

Comment: @cel it doesn't work too.

Comment: then check the path to `pip` and `jupyter` and see if you are using the right pip.

Comment: Are you installing Anaconda (not conda)?

Comment: Can you point us to which installation instructions you were using?

Answer (score 1):

After trying a bunch of solution, I found the quickest solution: using conda instead of pip.   Or just use anaconda, which provides jupyter, too.

Answer (score 0):

I meet withe the same problem when I use fish,when I switch to bash,everything works well!

Comment: Does this relate to jupyter?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a matter of agreeing to the Xcode License Agreement with: `sudo xcodebuild -license`, before running `sudo pip install notebook`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to use the following command in MacOS High Sierra 10.13.

`$HOME/anaconda3/bin/activate`